# How to select an integer randomly from a list containing integers as well as other objects?

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list

```
data=['_','_','A','B','C',1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to randomly get an integer among 1,2,3,4,5 
The list keeps getting modified so i cant just simply choose from the last 5 members

Here's what i tried but it throws an error retrieving the other members:

```
inp2=int(random.choice(data))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the non-integer items;

```
inp2 = ramdom.choice([x for x in data if isinstance(x, int)])
```

Comment: "The list keeps getting modified so i cant just simply choose from the last 5 members"

Comment: @user3650037 Happy to help:)

Answer (score 2):

Though it is almost similar to the answer of Neo, you can also try this:

```
inp2 = random.choice(filter(lambda d: isinstance(d, int), data))
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of last 5 elements.

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> data=['_','_','A','B','C',1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l = len(data)
>>> data[(l-5):l]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> k = data[(l-5):l]
>>> choice(k)
5
>>> choice(k)
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
random.choice([i for i in data[-5:] if isinstance(x, int)])
```

It is more safe for check type of data[-5:] by isinstance().

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import operator
inp2 = random.choice(filter(operator.isNumberType, data))
```

For this specific problem selecting last 5 elements also a good solution.

```
inp2 = random.choice(data[5:])
```

Comment: Your first solution will filter the numeric types, as in `int`, `float`, `long` etc. But OP needs only `int` types here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be creating another list, where would be just int values you want to pick from.
I don't know your specified assignment, but for example if you have a method for adding to your list, just add there:

```
def add(self, element):
   self.data.append(element)
   if type(element) == int:
      self.data_int.append(element)
```

and then just use:

```
def get_value(self):
   return random.choice(self.data_int)
```